# What is the use of Azure Key Vault in case of WebApp

Tags: azure, ssl, azure-keyvault

We have hosted our application on Azure WebAPP and wanted to use SSL on this. Should we use traditional way to attach this certification to Azure WebAPP or should we user Azure Key Vault. Since access to Azure WebAPP through RDP is not available and Azure is managing our WebAPP, can certification be compromised (if the Azure key vault is not used)?

I can understand its usage in case of VM, but on Azure, WebApp does it add any value.

Comment: If my understanding is right, you want to find this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/key-vault-use-from-web-application).

Answer (score 0):

Azure Web App doesn't rely on Azure Key Vault for any of its functionalities.

However, if you are using **App Service Certificate**, then you end up configuring **Azure Key Vault** for storing the secret. Other use cases are also there, but those are from an application perspective.